# Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) MySql Failure

Tags: centos, mysql

I am trying to install `MySql 5.6` on my `Centos 2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64`
but i get this error message.

```
 [root@Confluence-Host ~]# yum install mysql-server
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
  * base: mirror.intergrid.com.au
  * epel: mirror.intergrid.com.au
  * extras: mirror.ventraip.net.au
  * updates: centos.melbourneitmirror.net
 Setting up Install Process
 Package mysql-server is obsoleted by mysql-community-server, trying to install mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64 instead
 Resolving Dependencies
 --> Running transaction check
 ---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.40-2.el7 will be installed
 --> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-2.el7 for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 5.6.10 for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Running transaction check
 ---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.40-2.el7 will be installed
 --> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-libs(x86-64) >= 5.6.10 for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 ---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.40-2.el7 will be installed
 ---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.40-2.el7 will be installed
 --> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Running transaction check
 ---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.40-2.el7 will be installed
 --> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 ---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.6.40-2.el7 will be installed
 --> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-libs-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 ---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.40-2.el7 will be installed
 --> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64
 --> Finished Dependency Resolution
 Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
        Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
 Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
   Requires: systemd
 Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
   Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
 Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
   Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
 Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.6.40-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
   Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2):

it looks like that you have installed the EPEL repository for CentOS 7, but you are running CentOS 6.

Remove the `epel-release` package and/or the EPEL repo files from `/etc/yum.repos.d`, and try again with the correct package.